red thing on psensor tray menu
Im using ubuntu 24.04. this red things shows on psensor tray menu. when i switch to nvidia graphic card this things disappears. This is the issue Im speaking about:


Interesting observation. Did you have a question?

Yes. I try purge it and reinstalling it but dosen't fix. Do you have any suggestion?
